# Is there a better way to check for vowels in the first position of a word?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to check for a vowel as the first character of a word. For my code  I currently have this:

```
if first == 'a' or first == 'e' or first == 'i' or first == 'o' or first == 'u':
```

I was wondering is there a much better way to do this check or is this the best and most efficient way?

Comment: `if first in 'aeiou':`

Comment: When you say "first part of a word", do you mean the first character, or some an arbitrarily long section of the word?

Comment: @PTBNL I meant the first character

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try like this using the `in`:

```
if first.lower() in 'aeiou':
```

or better like

```
if first.lower() in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
```

Answer (score 7):

Better create a set of vowels, like this

```
>>> vowels = set('aeiouAEIOU')
>>> vowels
set(['a', 'A', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'I', 'u', 'O', 'E', 'U'])
```

and then check if `first` is one of them like this

```
>>> if first in vowels:
...
```

---

**Note:** The problem with

```
if first in 'aeiouAEIOU':
```

approach is, if your input is wrong, for example, if `first` is `'ae'`, then the test will fail.

```
>>> first = 'ae'
>>> first in 'aeiouAEIOU'
True
```

But `ae` is clearly not a vowel.

---

**Improvement:**

If it is just a one-time job, where you don't care to create a set beforehand, then you can use `if first in 'aeiouAEIOU':` itself, but check the length of `first` first, like this

```
>>> first = 'ae'
>>> len(first) == 1 and first in 'aeiouAEIOU'
False
```

Comment: I would think this is a non-issue, assuming the OP has defined `first` as a single character string (presumably like `first = my_str[0]`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex approach:

```py
from re import match

if match(r'^[aieou]', first):
    ...
```

This regular expression will match if the first character of "first" is a vowel.

Answer (score 1):

If your function is returning boolean value then easiest and simplest way will be

```
`bool(first.lower() in 'aeiou')`
```

Or

```
return first.lower() in 'aeiou'
```